# CSSでビット演算子？　.a:active ~ .b {

Tags: css

・下記CSSは、どういう意味でしょうか？

```
.a:active ~ .b {
```

・クラスaがアクティブ または、クラスbなら？
・cssにおける ~ はどういう意味でしょうか？
・否定？　ビット演算子？

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782054/what-does-the-css-tilde-squiggle-twiddle-selector-do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

間接セレクタですね。

2番目以降の要素に対して有効になると言えば良いでしょうか...

http://www.hp-stylelink.com/news/2013/09/20130912.php#lowList01